# Hibernate + JPA does not find the column for an @ElementCollection table

Tags: java, hibernate, embeddable

I am trying to add an `@ElementCollection` but the column is not found after the setup, so I constantly receive an error. I use Spring + flyway for the set up. Everything happens in the *public* schema

So here is my big object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_big_table")
MyBigObject{

   @Id
   @Column(name=COL_ID)
   @GeneratedValue(generator="gen_name")
   @GenericGenerator(
            name = "gen_name",
            strategy = "seq_name"
        )
   @AttributeAccessor(CommonConstants.HIBERNATE_ACCESS_PROPERTY)
   private long id;
    ...
    ...
        @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @CollectionTable(
            name = "my_small_table",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "big_object_id")
        )
    private List<MySmallObject> mySmallObjects;
}
```

Here is my embedded object:

```
@Embeddable
public class MySmallObject {

    @Column(name = "small_object_type")
    private String smallObjectType;
}
```

Then besides the existing *my_big_table* table I add *my_small_table* using flyway

```
create table if not exists my_small_table
(
    big_object_id      bigint not null,
    small_object_type     varchar(64) not null
);

alter table my_small_table
      add constraint FK_my_small_table
      foreign key (big_object_id)
      references my_big_table (id);
```

After this the my_small_table is successfully created but any instance of MyBigObject cannot be found because it looks for a column in the *my_small_table* that does not exist. As you can see it does not understand that the column name should use an underscore.

```
Big error trace ands with the following message:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column mysmalltab0_.smallobjecttype does 
not exist
09:17:24.994 INFO  - STDOUT:   Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "mysmalltab0_.smallobjecttype".
```

Do you know what I could forget? Could lombock annotations that I also use for both classes spoil the picture?

Comment: Note that `mysmalltab0_` normally is not the _table name_ that Hibernate will access but just an alias. Could you post the actual query? (You might need to enable query logging) Also try using a table name without underscores. I remember reading about some issues with underscores being transformed by default an `mysmalltab0_` indicates that Hibernate actually picked up that `my_small_table` from the annotation (at least that's the only place the code you've posted mentions it).

Comment: Please show where do you put `@Id` annotation on the `MyBigObject`. And could you please also show your hibernate config.

Comment: @SternK I added the id annotation

Comment: @Thomas all the tables in our project are with underscores, they were wroking pretty fine all the time. And it seems that deleting the table causes another error so I ssume it cannot find only the coumn

Comment: @user2957954 Try to remove the `@AttributeAccessor(CommonConstants.HIBERNATE_ACCESS_PROPERTY)` annotation.

Comment: @SternK what should I check in the hibernate config for? it's huge

Comment: @user2957954 Do you use the following properties: `hibernate.physical_naming_strategy`, `hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy`,
`hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers`?

Comment: @SternK these values are not set. Should they be defined?

Comment: @user2957954 No, they just may impact on this issue.

Comment: @SternK removing `@AttributeAccessor` really helped, thank you. Do you understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#access):

> By default, the placement of the `@Id` annotation gives the default access strategy. When placed on a field, Hibernate will assume field-based access. When placed on the identifier getter, Hibernate will use property-based access.

But the usage of the `@AttributeAccessor` leads to the changing access strategy for the field that hold `@Id` and as result your `@Column(name = "small_object_type")` annotation just was ignored. You can try to put it on the appropriate getter and it should work. But it's considered a good practiсe not to mix up access strategies for the entity fields.